# HTML rendering issue on scroll in WebView mac os x

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I have an button in right down corner in `Webview`. Button moves down or up as I scroll which should not be happen, as Same HTML we checked in Safari where it works fine and buttons position does not changed on scroll.

how can i fix such kind of issue and eager to know Why behaviour differs in safari and `WebView` for same HTML file ??

Looking for your valuable suggestion.

Thanks,

Comment: disable scrolling and then test if it is working.

Comment: @amrit_neo i am facing issue only on scroll. also how can i disable scrolling of WebView.

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable scrolling in your html as well as in Webview.

ie for HTML :

```
overflow : none
```

will do. And for cocoa webview you have to find a way, may be in .xib file you can do or go through the documentation.

Comment: @amit_neo- I tried by adding overflow:none in element tag but dint work out  :(